# For some reason, the interaction_check is interfering with the revoke button

Tags: python, discord.py

When I have the interaction check, the revoke button does not work. When I don't have the interaction check, the revoke button does work.

The acknowledge button should work under the condition that the person interacting is also the one who has received the infraction (userid option within the slash command), and the revoke button should only work for two roles, "Headquarters" and "First Line Supervisors".

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, user_id: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.user_id = user_id

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
        # check if the interaction user id is the same as the user id passed to the view
        userid = int(self.user_id)
        if interaction.user.id == userid and interaction.data["custom_id"] == "acknowledge":
            return True
        else:
            # send a message to the user that they cannot interact with the button
            await interaction.response.send_message("You are not authorized to use this button.", ephemeral=True)
            return False

    @discord.ui.button(label="Acknowledge", emoji="<:check:1135773225423491122>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="acknowledge")
    async def menu1(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        new_embed = Embed.from_dict(interaction.message.embeds[0].to_dict())
        new_embed.set_footer(text=f'Sent by {interaction.user.name}     |     Acknowledged: ✔')
        await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=new_embed)
        button.disabled = True
        await interaction.message.edit(view=self)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Revoke", emoji="<:Cross:1135773287880867900>", style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="revoke")
    async def menu2(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # rest of the code for the revoke button
        user = interaction.guild.get_member(interaction.user.id)
        role1 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=994233392478560297)
        role2 = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=994233182532685825)
        if role1 in user.roles or role2 in user.roles:
            await interaction.channel.send(f"**Punishment Revoked by {interaction.user.mention}**")
            await interaction.message.delete()
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have the required role to use this button.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.tree.command(name="infract")
@app_commands.describe(userid = "User being infracted (ID only)")
@app_commands.describe(reason = "Reason for infraction")
@app_commands.describe(type = "Choose a type")
@app_commands.choices(type=[
    Choice(name='Termination', value=1),
    Choice(name='Demotion', value=2),
    Choice(name='Infraction', value=3),
    Choice(name="Blacklist", value=4),
    Choice(name="Under Investigation", value=5)
])
@app_commands.describe(note = "Any notes that should appear on the command response (put N/A if none)")
@app_commands.describe(acknowledge = "Should there be an acknowledge button?")
@app_commands.choices(acknowledge=[
    Choice(name='Yes', value=1),
    Choice(name='No', value=2)
])
```

I've tried to change the position of the interaction check, but that did not help and just made things worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the logic of the `interaction_check` function.

```
async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
    # check if the interaction user id is the same as the user id passed to the view
    userid = int(self.user_id)
    if interaction.user.id == userid and interaction.data["custom_id"] == "acknowledge":
        return True
    else:
        # send a message to the user that they cannot interact with the button
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not authorized to use this button.", ephemeral=True)
        return False
```

The first check, `interaction.user.id == userid and interaction.data["custom_id"] == "acknowledge"`, first checks if the user id matches, AND if the button clicked has the custom id of "acknowledge". If not, then it would fail.

So if the user, with or without the matching user id, clicks on "revoke", the check will still fail.

Since the callback of "revoke" already has its own check so as to only work for the two roles, you can remove the additional requirement in the check and only check for the user id.

```
async def interaction_check(self, interaction: discord.Interaction) -> bool:
    userid = int(self.user_id)
    if not (check := interaction.user.id == userid): #  Simplifying code
        await interaction.response.send_message("You are not authorized to use this button.", ephemeral=True)
    return check
```

The problem here lies on the function's logic, not the function itself. You can always modify it to suit your intended purpose.

Comment: Thanks for helping! This did not fix the issue, however, I found a better way to handle it. Instead of using the interaction check for the entire view, I used if
        ```if interaction.user.id == userid:
            await interaction.response.edit_message(embed=new_embed)
            button.disabled = True
            await interaction.message.edit(view=self)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have the required role to use this button.", ephemeral=True)```

This was placed in the individual buttons (with edits to accommodate, of course)

Comment: Glad to hear that! It's always good go through the logical flow of your program to understand what the problem is. Happy coding!